# How to mix different styles of programming on several languages?

Tags: programming-languages, coding-style

I know that Senior Developer doesn't use only one language and only one platform or IDE.

Can you advise how to mix different styles of programming to make efficient code?

For example, **best** mixing is **Perl + Objective-C**.

`$ObjectiveCLongNameOfVariablesAndMethods` are worst for Perl-style, but good for iOS-team.

`[self method:[[NSArray alloc] initWithobjects:[hash objectForKey:name]]]` style is weird for an eye, but not for perl simple-looking arrays and hashes and autovivification.

Also, i try to mixing **SAS + Objective-C style**, but here i have a trouble. **SAS** doesn't support names long names, only 32 symbols. So, big trouble to naming variables.

Another difficulty is features of current language. So, if I can't use current language for a task, that it can **solve 'like a BOSS'**, I become angry and see weird code. Using libraries is good, but it makes code not natural, 'cause eating soup with fork is strange'.

And at the end: where can I trust compiler and interpreter of language? So, **C++-style** is best for pointers (you make destructors, constructors, etc.), but many languages now support mechanism like **ARC in Objective-C** or don't use pointers (like **C#**).

Comment: -1: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: problem is: how to mix different styles of coding from several languages. as an answer, i see, that there is no good practice of mixing coding-styles of languages

Comment: The right tool for the job. Use the language you know best that fits the job at hand the best. Use the conventions of that language. Take programming style with you between languages (i.e. logic and algorithms that solve problems rather than the actual statements themselves - like pseudo code) by all means - but don't expect them always to be easy to code or as efficeint as another way of doing it in the second language. Thus, take concepts and ideas (higher level style) and stick to the language's own paradigms and syntax.

Comment: This is the problem of general approaches in coding (besides patterns) I'm also interested in. I invite you to discuss a similar question but more specifically: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/307083/javascript-closure-style-similar-to-java-class-structure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep to the conventions of the language being used.

When using Objective C, keep Objective C conventions in those parts of the code. When using Perl keep to Perl conventions... etc.. etc... etc...

This keeps things more compartmentalized - when you move to a different language it is easier to see that you have moved to it, and others that are used to the language conventions would also have an easier time.

**Don't** try to get one set of conventions for all the languages you use - this will just make things harder in the long run.

Comment: ok, but if i move to another language, what kind experience i could take to it from another language-coding practice?

Comment: @loldop - You need to understand that conventions are _per_ language. Most languages do not share conventions (not fully). I can't tell you what you can take, as this is a very vague question.

Comment: @loldop: you can take a lot of higher-level wisdom with you, but as far as coding style goes, the rule of thumb is "when in Rome, do like the Romans do".

Comment: I think both sides should be considered - not only conventions. In Steve McConnell’s Code Complete it is recommended to make a difference between programming in a language and programming into a language (stricktly native conventions). A good article on this by Jon Skeet: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/04/23/programming-quot-in-quot-a-language-vs-programming-quot-into-quot-a-language/

Answer (score 1):

Base your styles and conventions on the language being used.

You may love "{'s" everywhere in your code. You always use a series of "[" and "{" and "(" in the most verbose form. You believe they should be on their own line. Then one day your team is assigned a large development task that requires python. If you don't adapt your style, you will never get your python code to run. Those braces all have different meanings in python, the language where white space has meaning, and the difference between a list and a dictionary is the style of brace.